# How to 3DPlot a triple integral in cartesian coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, integral-equations

I am trying to make a 3d graph of the triple integral in cartesian coordinates. I am positive that I have been filling out the correct parameters but I am unsure what could be wrong. [image]

[image: attmept]

Additionally I was wondering whether it would be possible to do this in spherical and cylindrical form or if Mathematica had the ability to convert the triple integral to those forms.

Comment: Please post copyable code, not images. People here usually want to test their solutions on their own copy of _Mathematica_, but nobody wants to retype everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RegionPlot3D[-5 < x < 5 && -Sqrt[5^2 - x^2] < y < Sqrt[5^2 - x^2] && 
   Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < z < Sqrt[50 - x^2 - y^2], 
{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -2, 8}, PlotPoints -> 60
  ]
```

[image]